# resizing google material icons font size

Tags: html, css

According to the official guide, adding "md-48" to the class is supposed the resize the font to 48px, yet here it's not working. Am I missing something? 
I also tried using CSS to set the font size of .material-icons to 48px yet it remains unaffected.

```css
/*.material-icons{
    font-size: 48px;
}*/
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid mobileMenu">
            <i class="material-icons md-48">list</i>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add directly in the tag the size of the icon, or add a CSS class to do this:

```css
.material-icons.md-60 { font-size: 60px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid mobileMenu">
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:60px;">list</i>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid mobileMenu">
  <i class="material-icons md-60">list</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about material icons and their css classes.
But if you just use `!important` you can overwrite the fontsize.

```css
.md-48 {
  font-size: 48px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid mobileMenu">
  <i class="material-icons">list</i>
  <i class="material-icons md-48">list</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the updated google icons you can add font-size to the provided google CSS or you can add a new class to your icon then provide it with a font-size property.

```css
/* Option 1 */
.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-size:30px;
  font-variation-settings:
    'FILL' 1,
    'wght' 400,
    'GRAD' 0,
    'opsz' 0
}

/* Option 2 */
.icon{
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem here. In my case, I was using CSS to try to change the size of the icons but without success.

Turns out my font-size definition was being overriden by the Google's default font-size definition (24px) that comes when we call the Google Fonts stylesheet. And it was being overriden because I was calling Google Fonts stylesheet **after** calling my own stylesheet.

With this, any font-size definitions in styles.css to the icon won't work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/...">
```

To solve this, in your HTML file, put the call to the Google Fonts stylesheet **before** the call to your stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/...">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

This way, the font-size definition in your CSS to the Google Fonts or Google Icons class will override Google's defaults and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer somewhere on stackoverflow which works perfect for me:

```
.send-icon {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```